# Windows 2003 server becomes very slow while executing query that retrieves lac's of records

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I executed a `query`, which retrieves more than 100,000 records, which uses joins to retrieve the records.
While this query was running the whole server becomes very slow and this affects other sites, which try to run normal query to get records.
In this case, query which runs for getting that many number of records and other query running simultaneously are of different data base.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question? Please read [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) to ask a good question.

Answer (score 0):

Your query retrieving [hundreds of thousands](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakh) of records is probably causing significant IO and trashes the buffer pool. You need to address this from two directions:

- review your requirements. *Why* are you retrieving hundreds of thousands of records? For sure no human can look at so many. Any analysis should be pushed to be performed on the server and only retrieve aggregate results
- Why do you need to analyze frequently hundreds of thousands of records? Perhaps you need an ETL pipeline to extract the required aggregates/summation on a daily basis
- Maybe the query does *need* to analyse hundreds of thousands of records, perhaps you're missing an index
- If all of the above don't apply it simply means you need a bigger boat. Your current hardware cannot handle the requirements.